# Getting "Cannot add instance of type EventTriggerBehavior to collection BehaviorCollection" to make clickable TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, behavior, xamlparseexception

My app had a series of buttons hardcoded to be a navigation menu, but I wanted to upgrade this to something more data-driven.

```
    <Button Content="MyPage">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="Namespace.MyPage"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```

But when I tried to put this behavior on a different XAML element (specifically a TextBlock as part of a data template) I got the following error.

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in NavMockUp.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type
>   'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a
>   collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'

```
    <TextBlock Text="Click for Page">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="Namespace.MyPage"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Make sure you understand how EventTriggerBehaviors work**

The error may be somewhat unhelpful, but this is being caused by the fact that a TextBlock element does not have an event called "Click" to attach to. Jerry Nixon has a [good article on behaviors](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/10/everything-i-know-about-behaviors-in.html)

To fix this simply replace the Click event with the Tapped event, because a TextBlock *does* have one of those.

```
    <TextBlock Text="Click for Page">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="Namespace.MyPage"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
```